# Class '\App\User' not found в Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Перенес класс `User` в папку *Models*. Изменил `namespace` в классе. Изменил `'model' => 'App\Models\User'` в *config/auth.php*, все равно ошибка

> Class '\App\User' not found.

робовал *в composer.json* в

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
```

добавлять  в `app/Models` и делал `composer dump-autoload` - не помогает. В *config/auth.php* в значение  `'model' =>` подставлял всякую чушь, все равно пишет:

> Class '\App\User' not found.

Такое ощущение, что не берется информация из *config/auth.php* Подскажите, что еще можно попробовать, чтоб *User* нашелся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После манипуляций с настройками необходимо очистить и пересоздать кеш конфигов.

В командной строке в проекте выполните

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!